# Tilt Compensated Compass with external Magnetometer and Accelerometer

Tags: ios, swift, accelerometer, trigonometry

I am trying to write an app to take the raw data from a BLE connected Magnetometer and Accelerometer to create a tilt compensated compass. My code is:

func tiltCompass (AxR: Float, AyR: Float, AzR: Float, MxR: Float, MyR: Float, MzR: Float) -> (Float, pitch: Float, roll: Float, accelration: Float, magnitude: Float){

```
//AxR, AyR, AzR = Raw accelerometer readings in milli G
//MxR, MyR, MzR = Raw magnotometer readings in milli guass

let pitch           = atan2(AxR, sqrtf(powf(AyR, 2)+powf(AzR, 2)))  //p .. asin(-AxR)
let roll            = atan2(AyR, sqrtf(powf(AxR, 2)+powf(AzR, 2)))  //γ .. asin(AyR/acos(pitch))

let acceleration    = sqrt(powf(AxR, 2) + powf(AyR,2) + powf(AzR, 2)) //if not equal to 1 then linear or angular Acceleration detectec
let magnitude       = sqrt(powf(MxR, 2) + powf(MyR,2) + powf(MzR, 2)) //if not equal to 1 then mag interefence or pitch/roll present

//MxC, MyC, MzC =  Tilt compensated magnetic sensor measurements
let MxC             = (MxR * acos(pitch)) + (MzR * asin(pitch))
let MyC             = (MxR * asin(roll) * asin(pitch)) + (MyR * acos(roll)) - (MzR * asin(roll) * acos(pitch))
let MzC             = (-MxR * acos(roll) * asin(pitch)) + (MyR * asin(roll)) + (MzR * acos(roll) * acos(pitch))

//Heading
    var heading : Float = 0
    if MxC > 0 && MyC >= 0 {heading = atan2f(MyC,MxC)}
    else if MxC < 0 {heading = 180 + atan2f(MyC,MxC)}
    else if MxC > 0 && MyC <= 0 {heading = 360 + atan2f(MyC,MxC)}
    else if MxC == 0 && MyC < 0 {heading = 90}
    else if MxC == 0 && MyC > 0 {heading = 270}

return (heading, pitch, roll, acceleration, magnitude)
```

}

When run and output to the console for testing I get the following results:

```
`print ("Tilt Heading :: \(titlheading)"`)
```

Raw Output, through a slow 360 rotation of device using a 0.5ms sample rate:

```
Tilt Heading :: (359.583313, 0.0420875959, -0.00037289664, 981.505249, 140.133362)
Tilt Heading :: (359.620483, 0.0400086045, 0.000686392013, 977.575562, 141.776596)
Tilt Heading :: (359.604218, 0.0409856997, -0.000686022104, 978.102661, 140.800262)
Tilt Heading :: (359.621552, 0.0415208116, 0.0, 980.199829, 141.251465)
Tilt Heading :: (359.605988, 0.0415050909, -0.000996833201, 979.100708, 143.005798)
Tilt Heading :: (359.617432, 0.0315867998, -0.0142858513, 952.233215, 141.984436)
Tilt Heading :: (359.66037, 0.0344147533, 0.00562020484, 976.83783, 143.398621)
Tilt Heading :: (359.780029, 0.0266412869, 0.00737870578, 975.518738, 142.221939)
Tilt Heading :: (359.845642, 0.0286898259, 0.000808929733, 980.307739, 139.077515)
Tilt Heading :: (359.875763, 0.0289015751, -0.00155698066, 979.460205, 131.390213)
Tilt Heading :: (359.960602, 0.0238598455, 0.0107485456, 981.826172, 127.953026)
Tilt Heading :: (0.0993536413, 0.0159567893, 0.0109700477, 978.684509, 119.979263)
Tilt Heading :: (0.211536095, 0.0434884764, -0.0195928887, 980.775757, 107.317924)
Tilt Heading :: (0.325962782, 0.0267457329, 0.0152643193, 983.115173, 94.8423309)
Tilt Heading :: (0.332540244, 0.0264445059, 0.00895909593, 980.469238, 83.6867523)
Tilt Heading :: (0.344065964, 0.0380582735, -0.00623759581, 977.947266, 72.580513)
Tilt Heading :: (0.430158406, 0.02798892, 0.00858225394, 980.873291, 67.669838)
Tilt Heading :: (0.370779216, 0.0302195679, 0.00629223092, 979.150513, 63.4612465)
Tilt Heading :: (0.289538383, 0.0335264429, -0.00168223935, 979.052612, 55.8212128)
Tilt Heading :: (0.178537324, 0.0272957645, 0.0116259437, 981.189819, 48.8469582)
Tilt Heading :: (359.930176, 0.0456191301, 0.0042596627, 973.78894, 46.9943542)
Tilt Heading :: (0.114507265, 0.0474723466, 0.00697499886, 979.506409, 48.846962)
Tilt Heading :: (359.87915, 0.0223429911, 0.0201583095, 977.479614, 49.1066818)
Tilt Heading :: (359.463013, 0.041566588, 0.006531836, 980.588928, 45.7328796)
Tilt Heading :: (359.108643, 0.0457907319, 0.00280253845, 979.47052, 58.2302399)
Tilt Heading :: (359.009003, 0.0519429594, -0.00353998039, 982.210876, 61.2032242)
Tilt Heading :: (359.018799, 0.0453071184, 0.000811007048, 977.796753, 72.7237701)
Tilt Heading :: (358.989746, 0.0428104326, 0.0182086546, 974.919983, 86.2864609)
Tilt Heading :: (359.111145, 0.0405384526, 0.001929875, 979.856873, 105.036392)
Tilt Heading :: (359.134888, 0.037665993, -0.00355373905, 978.408142, 111.559624)
Tilt Heading :: (359.195068, 0.0360276364, -0.0083027631, 977.155823, 122.110992)
Tilt Heading :: (359.29718, 0.0381992422, -0.0127511648, 975.937317, 133.16391)
Tilt Heading :: (359.361481, 0.0402125083, -0.01025254, 981.725281, 140.315903)
Tilt Heading :: (359.467102, 0.0443913862, -0.00392110227, 980.084106, 141.815857)
Tilt Heading :: (359.544525, 0.0404609852, -0.00336046354, 980.223816, 143.996384)
Tilt Heading :: (359.563568, 0.0364769474, -0.00716915308, 978.506104, 146.075821)
Tilt Heading :: (359.625275, 0.0326416567, -0.00985956006, 977.54425, 143.6297)
Tilt Heading :: (359.677765, 0.0283227563, -0.0191305373, 975.776978, 145.19458)
Tilt Heading :: (359.717773, 0.0356077142, 0.000437195326, 976.680237, 146.306961)
Tilt Heading :: (359.759583, 0.0338454209, -0.00644258223, 975.236816, 144.856705)
Tilt Heading :: (359.798248, 0.0389000885, -0.00695806136, 981.890625, 141.389816)
Tilt Heading :: (359.821259, 0.0386202037, -0.00193677912, 976.363892, 144.480133)
Tilt Heading :: (359.794495, 0.0383632295, 0.000625674089, 974.948547, 143.698517)
Tilt Heading :: (359.801819, 0.0391565114, 0.000623352069, 978.580322, 143.317673)
Tilt Heading :: (359.799316, 0.0375518836, 0.0, 976.505432, 146.329071)
```

And raw MxC and MxY Output:

```
MxC :: 136.499 :: MyC :: 64.3293
MxC :: 141.945 :: MyC :: 72.8294
MxC :: 138.629 :: MyC :: 67.2004
MxC :: 141.684 :: MyC :: 74.0713
MxC :: 142.802 :: MyC :: 87.7088
MxC :: 140.387 :: MyC :: 100.164
MxC :: 132.326 :: MyC :: 112.583
MxC :: 127.345 :: MyC :: 114.873
MxC :: 128.753 :: MyC :: 114.533
MxC :: 121.509 :: MyC :: 119.921
MxC :: 116.456 :: MyC :: 136.453
MxC :: 97.3599 :: MyC :: 146.399
MxC :: 84.349 :: MyC :: 141.576
MxC :: 69.9021 :: MyC :: 146.072
MxC :: 54.5572 :: MyC :: 144.087
MxC :: 40.0276 :: MyC :: 148.076
MxC :: 32.3366 :: MyC :: 136.623
MxC :: 18.0619 :: MyC :: 135.039
MxC :: 7.25728 :: MyC :: 117.712
MxC :: 1.14393 :: MyC :: 101.884
MxC :: -3.98472 :: MyC :: 87.3294
MxC :: -6.75507 :: MyC :: 74.646
MxC :: -10.5574 :: MyC :: 52.1823
MxC :: -2.05467 :: MyC :: 40.4278
MxC :: 6.91559 :: MyC :: 33.662
MxC :: 10.0441 :: MyC :: 33.2202
MxC :: 10.5631 :: MyC :: 39.0956
MxC :: 13.7499 :: MyC :: 17.9752
MxC :: 30.0131 :: MyC :: -1.86769
MxC :: 68.7336 :: MyC :: -26.9304
MxC :: 97.4751 :: MyC :: -18.8135
MxC :: 124.867 :: MyC :: -8.67472
MxC :: 143.179 :: MyC :: 24.6331
MxC :: 151.311 :: MyC :: 55.8918
MxC :: 151.278 :: MyC :: 75.1455
MxC :: 152.033 :: MyC :: 69.4944
MxC :: 149.935 :: MyC :: 75.8773
MxC :: 153.172 :: MyC :: 74.0412
MxC :: 153.288 :: MyC :: 72.4933
MxC :: 149.411 :: MyC :: 77.2322
MxC :: 149.469 :: MyC :: 75.1191
MxC :: 149.95 :: MyC :: 78.3858
```

Not sure where I have gone wrong. Spent a long time working on this and researching on the web. Any help?

Comment: What is wrong about the output? What values do you expect?

Comment: Hi, the output stays predominately around 359.159 also I would expect the 'acceleration' and 'magnitudes' to be close to or less than 1?

Answer (score 0):

You want the numbers around 359.xx to show up as small negative numbers. Is that right?

In this case I'd add a computed attribute to the class, like this:

```
    var normalizedX: Double = {
        let x1 = x % 360.0
        return x1 > 180.0 ? (x1 - 360.0) : x1
    }
```

EDIT: Another issue might be, that atanf, acos and they all are working with radians +-PI and not 0..360. See here for more details: [atanf man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/atan2.3.html)

Comment: Hi, not sure I understand your answer. It appears that my output isn't working correctly. I would add more data to show a slow rotation around 360 with a 0.5 sec sample rate but I can not upload a file.

Comment: Ok. I see. My answer is more to normalize after the problem happened. We're looking only for 'heading', right? First, I would write the code as if-else-if blocks. At least with MxC == 0 && MyC == 0 you have two if's firering.  That might explain the jumps to 360 but not to 180. What do you see when you print out the two M's and the heading?

Comment: Hi Jboi. I've modified my code to use 'if else if' and added the raw output from MxC and MyC to the original post. Still getting the same incorrect readings.

Comment: Actually the difference might simply be degrees and radiants.

Comment: Hi, yes. I see that. Pretty sure my calculations for MxC and MyC are wrong as  they are too large to be Radians. Pitch and Roll are in radians though.